# What is the difference of returning a promise() or a deferred in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

Let's say I have an ajax method which doesn't has a promise to return, so I'd do something like this:

```
promises.setPreferredService = function(id) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  nsAddressAjaxService.setPreferredAddress(id, {
    callback: function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise(); // I could also return only `deferred`
};
```

In my method's return, I can return `deferred.promise()` or just return the `deferred` and both of them I can do this:

```
promises.setPreferrredService.done(callback);
```

So what's the difference of returning `deferred.promise()` or only return `deferred` ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Comment: Not really... But thanks for the reference.

Comment: Why didn't you do that before asking? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/139010

Comment: BTW standard promises are specified here - https://promisesaplus.com/ There are many promise implementations, but jQuery's is not exactly conformant, bear that in mind while learning.

Comment: Well @MattBall, you probably go to every single post here in stackoverflow and asks the same question to other developers, since there's a lot more questions that has answers in the docs than only mine. The thing is, I asked here first, and some guys answered, and they are fast and simple answers. Maybe this question will help another lazy developer that doesn't want to look at the docs.

Comment: "They did it too" doesn't make it okay for you to do the same.

Comment: Ok, the question has been answered, I'm happy with that. Maybe this will help others. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Kos support is coming in jQuery 3.0 which will be promises/A+ compliant

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Wow, thanks! I'm really looking forward to that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So what's the difference of returning `deferred.promise()` or only return `deferred` ?

You want to return `deferred.promise()` so that the calling code can't call `resolve` or `reject` or other Deferred-specific methods. That's not something the caller should have access to. It should only be able to *consume* the promise, not affect its state.

Answer (score 3):

You should not expose `deferred`, but only the *read only* `promise`.

The `deferred` is the mechanism for controlling completion of an action, but the `promise` is just a way of seeing the results. You do not want external methods to be able to *complete* or *reject* the operation.

Answer (score 3):

A promise doesn't expose the interface that allows to resolve it. You can only await the result and do operations on it.

A deferred is more than a promise - it also allows you to resolve or reject it.

Answer (score 2):

If you return the actual `deferred`, then the caller can `resolve` it by calling  `deferred.resolve()`.  You want to return the promise so that the caller can chain it, etc., but not actually decide its resolution.